How to show that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{|X|\geq k} |X| d \mathbb{P}=0$
I am learning probability theory. While doing so I encountered the following statement:

If a random variable X, is integrable one can easily see that $\lim_{k
 \rightarrow \infty} \int_{|X|\geq k} |X| d \mathbb{P}=0$.

The thing is, I do not see why.
For that reason I would like to prove this statement.
So let $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\int_{\Omega} |X| d \mathbb{P} < \infty$.
Since we are working with a mesure, the integral is defined as
$\int X d \mathbb{P}=sup\{\sum_k c_k \mathbb{P}(A_k)\}$ for disjoint sets $A_j$.
Thus $\int_{|X|\geq k} |X| d \mathbb{P}=sup \{\sum_k |c_k| \mathbb{P}(A_k) \}$.
Since $\int_{\Omega} X d \mathbb{P} < \infty$, denote the sequence $s_n:=\int_{|X(\omega)|\geq n} |X| d \mathbb{P} < \infty$ for all $n$.
That's where I got stuck. I know that I need to somehow use the $\int |X| d\mathbb{P}< \infty $ condition to get the result. But I don't know how.

Obvious consequence of Dominated Convergence Theorem.

@geetha290krm I do not see how.

This has been asked any number of times on MSE.

This question is similar to: Proving an integral with random variables tends to $0$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To expand on geetha290krm's comment: Consider $X_k = |X| \mathbb{1}_{|X|\geq k}$; the sequence $(X_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise to $0$ and is dominated by the integrable r.v. $|X|$.  By the dominated convergence theorem,
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_{|x|\geq k} |x|~d\mathbb{P} = \lim_{k\to\infty} \mathbb{E}X_k = \mathbb{E}[\lim_{k\to\infty} X_k] = 0.$$
Alternatively, you could use the monotone convergence theorem on the same sequence (why?).

I am not sure if this argument works but if you have a measure space $(Y , \mathcal{S}, \mu)$ and an integrable function $f:Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ you can define a measure $\nu : \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ by
$$A \mapsto \nu (A) = \int_A f d\mu$$
In your case you have a measurable function |X| and a sequence of measurable sets $A_k = \{|X| > k\}$. Then your questions reduces to finding:
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty } \nu (A_k)$$
Where
$$\nu(A_k) = \int_{A_k}|X| dP$$
And at this point you may want to user certain property of a measure.
